# how to compare rows based on reference from another column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif, array-formulas

how can I check numbers in a range **A1:A20** if they are not same and put that in cell **E1**

and then check range **B1:B20** and if any row in **B** column consists of number "**1**" then from range **A1:A20** check only rows where rows are set "**1**" in column **B** and check them if they are not same and put that into **E2**

it should look like this:
[image]

so far I have only this piece `=IF(COUNTIF($A$1<>$A$2);"OK";)"NOT OK")` but stacking more `<>$A$3<>$A$4<>$A$5...` brokes it

Comment: @Pierre44 yes. `A1,A5,A10,A12,A13,A18` are not the same thus those are "*chosen*" and they are "**OK**" because they are different. however range `A1:A20` is "**NOT OK**" because `A4` and `A5` are same. why is screenshot wrong?

Comment: Are you checking if each row matches the row above, or below, or either side?

Comment: @RET all of them. for instance `A1` shall check **all** other 19 rows in A column, then `A2` shall check aganist `A1` and range `A3:A20` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an easy way to do it.

Can you add three new columns (hide them afterwards if you'd like)? If so insert two new columns after column B.

In C1 put

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$20, A1)
```

Drag that formula down until C20.
Now in H1, put:

```
=IF(AVERAGE(C1:C20)=1, "OK", "NOT OK")
```

Now for the second part...

In D1 put:

```
=IF(B1=1, A1, "")
```

In E1 put:

```
=IF(B1 = 1, COUNTIF($D$1:$D$20, D1), "")
```

And drag it down.

In H2, put:

```
=IF(AVERAGE(E1:E20)=1, "OK", "NOT OK")
```

Comment: this works for `G1` part but not for 2nd part (G2). `G2` returns "**NOT OK**" but should return "**OK**"

Answer (score 1):

With one helping Column:

In C1 Put

```
=IF(B1="";"";COUNTIFS($A$1:A1;A1;$B$1:B1;1))
```

and drag it down

In E1 Put

```
=IF(COUNTA(A1:A20)-SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A1:A20;A1:A20))=0;"OK";"NOT OK")
```

In E2 Put

```
=IF(MAX(C1:C20)>1;"NOT OK";"OK")
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution is to use array formula:

**Checking for unique entries in the full range**

In G1 put

```
= SUM( COUNTIF( $A$1:$A$20, $A$1:$A$20 ) )
```

and turn this into an array formula by holding down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> & <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> when pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Then in G2 put

```
= COUNT( $A$1:$A$20 )
```

And in E1 put

```
= IF( G1 = G2, "OK", "Not OK" )
```

This solves checking for unique entries across the full selection.

**Checking for unique entries across a selection**

Similar approach, but using a SUMPRODUCT.

In H1 put

```
= SUMPRODUCT( COUNTIFS( $A$1:$A$20, $A$1:$A$20, $B$1:$B$20, ">0" ), $B$1:$B$20 )
```

and turn it into an array formula (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>)

In H2 put

```
= SUM( $B$1:$B$20)
```

And in E2 put

```
= IF( H1 = H2, "OK", "Not OK" )
```

I think you could also have this check full columns (rather than a defined range) by change (for instance) `$A$1:$A$20` to `$A:$A` but haven't checked.

Comment: this works for `E1` part but not for 2nd part (E2). `E2` returns "**NOT OK**" but should return "**OK**"

Comment: changed the formula for H1, needed to have a nested COUNTIFS rather than COUNTIF

Comment: now `E1` returns "**NOT OK**" even if numbers in **A** are different. `E2` part works.

Comment: all I can think is to check that you still have an array formula in G1 (visible with curly brackets around the formula)?

Comment: by following your steps I have this in **G1**: `= ArrayFormula(SUM( COUNTIF( $A$1:$A$20; $A$1:$A$20 ) ))`

Comment: what I'd expect you to have is `{= (SUM( COUNTIF( $A$1:$A$20; $A$1:$A$20 ) ) }` which is the same formula but denoted as being an array formula by the {} wrappers - I've not seen ArrayFormula used like that so guessing you're using a different (newer?!) version of Excel

Comment: I'm wondering whether this is an issue with the length of the number/strings - I've just pulled in your dataset and excel rounded it to roughly 10 significant figures; changing it to text keeps the full numbers (need to change the COUNT formulas in G1/H1 to COUNTA) but the array formulas still can't tell the difference between values if they're beyond the sig-fig limit

Comment: **IF** this is the problem, you can get round it by pre-processing the dataset so that it's clearly strings rather than numbers (for instance insert a space in the middle in a consistent manner)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169956/discussion-between-domw-and-judgedredd).